# How to cut specific url in python

Tags: python, string

How to cut in this url bold elements:
'https://www.leon.bet/ru/bets/tennis/itf-men/2021-itf-netherlands-f1-men-singles/ **1970324838748344** -ritschard-a-mateus-alves'
without /2021.

Ill tried with regex pattern = r'/\d+'  #not good for this example

It is ideal not to include other libraries. The links can be of different lengths and sometimes contain numbers in front of the id I need, sometimes they do not.

Comment: what is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format is constant (i.e. the id is always the first thing after the last '/' and it is always followed by '-') you can do the following:

```
>>> s = 'https://www.leon.bet/ru/bets/tennis/itf-men/2021-itf-netherlands-f1-men-singles/1970324838748344-ritschard-a-mateus-alves'
>>> s.split('/')[-1].split('-')[0]
'1970324838748344'
```

Explanation:

The first `split` is getting us a list of the strings separated by '/', from which we extract the last. The second `split` takes that string we just got and further splits it into words separated by '-', from which we extract the first.

Answer (score 0):

Assmue you want to remove `1970324838748344` but keep `2021`:

```
import re

s = 'https://www.leon.bet/ru/bets/tennis/itf-men/2021-itf-netherlands-f1-men-singles/1970324838748344-ritschard-a-mateus-alves'
replaced = re.sub(r'\d{5,}', '', s)
print(replaced)
# https://www.leon.bet/ru/bets/tennis/itf-men/2021-itf-netherlands-f1-men-singles/-ritschard-a-mateus-alves
```